# Excel VBA - Error in variable in cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

My company has a production worksheet that has a list of about 20 company ids down column B (not in numeric order). The user keys an id in cell E2 and a macro updates cells in that row, from columns K-P.

I want to loop through the rows to find the one that matches the selection and copy from columns K-P to D-I.

This test version only has 3 rows.

```vb
Sub testRad()

Dim StartAddress As String
Dim EndAddress As String
Dim c As Range

top_row = 9
bottom_row = 11

this_row = top_row

For Each c In Range("B9:B11")
    
    If c.Value = Range("E2").Value Then
        StartAddress = "K" & CStr(this_row)
        EndAddress = "P" & CStr(this_row)
        
        ActiveCell.Range("cstr(StartAddress):cstr(EndAddress)").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Offset = c

        ' for testing
        Range("D9").Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    this_row = this_row + 1
end Sub
```

The line

```
ActiveCell.Range("cstr(StartAddress):cstr(EndAddress)").Select
```

Results in an error:

> Run-time error '1004':
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```vb
Sub testRad()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
  
    Set ws = Activesheet
    For Each c In ws.Range("B9:B11").Cells
        If c.Value = ws.Range("E2").Value Then
            With c.EntireRow
                .Range("K1:P1").Copy .Range("D1") 'range is *relative to c.EntireRow*
            end with
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

- Most of the time (always), it's a bad idea to retrieve the addresses of cells when trying to reference ranges: use range objects instead.
- Your error needs no explanation because `cstr(StartAddress):cstr(EndAddress)` is not a valid address. Instead, you could have used the following:

  ```
  CStr(StartAddress) & ":" & CStr(EndAddress)
  ```

which besides the redundant converting of strings to strings, wouldn't help much anyway.

[image]

**An Improvement**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateCompanyData()

    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Company Data"
    
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "E2"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS As String = "K:P"
    Const DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "B9"
    Const DST_FIRST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "D"

    ' Reference the worksheet.

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Store the (source) lookup value in a variable
    ' and reference the source return range.
    
    Dim srrg As Range, sVal As Variant
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_LOOKUP_CELL)
        sVal = .Value
        If IsError(sVal) Then Exit Sub ' don't lookup an error value
        Set srrg = .EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination (single-column) lookup range.
    
    Dim dlrg As Range
    With ws.Range(DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
        Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dlCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in dst. lookup column
        Set dlrg = .Resize(dlCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Attempt to match the (source) lookup value in the (destination)
    ' lookup range to return the (destination) row index.
    
    Dim drIndex: drIndex = Application.Match(sVal, dlrg, 0)
    
    ' Copy the values from the source to the destination return range.
    
    Dim drrg As Range, IsMatchFound As Boolean ' for the message box
    
    If IsNumeric(drIndex) Then ' match found
        ' Reference the destination return range.
        Set drrg = dlrg.Rows(drIndex).EntireRow _
            .Columns(DST_FIRST_RETURN_COLUMN).Resize(, srrg.Columns.Count)
        ' Copy values.
        drrg.Value = srrg.Value
        IsMatchFound = True
    'Else ' match not found; do nothing
    End If

    ' Inform.
    
    If IsMatchFound Then
        MsgBox """" & sVal & """-data updated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox """" & sVal & """ not found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub
```